# DrRacket - render every structure in a list

Tags: list, recursion, racket, racket-student-languages

```
(define SCENE (empty-scene 500 500))
(define-struct pos (x y))
(define-struct ball (img pos))

;(define (render lst))



(define game (list
               (make-ball (circle 10 "solid" "blue") (make-pos 250 250))
               (make-ball (circle 10 "solid" "red") (make-pos 150 150))))

(big-bang game
  [to-draw render])
```

Lets say i just want to render all my ball-struct-elements in the list on the SCENE. How can i do this? I know how to do it without a list, but with a list i got some problems.

Im using the beginner student version of racket.

I am thankful for every answer

I tried it recursive but just cant work it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [2.3.4 Placing Images & Scenes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28part._.Placing_.Images___.Scenes%29) for functions like [`place-image`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._place-image%29%29) or [`place-images`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/teachpack/2htdpimage.html#%28def._%28%28lib._2htdp%2Fimage..rkt%29._place-images%29%29).

Function `place-images` requires using [`posn`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/htdp/index.html#%28def._%28%28lib._lang%2Fposn..rkt%29._posn%29%29) structure. If you want to use your own `pos` structure, you will have to use `place-image`.

Beginning Student Language also doesn't provide [`foldl`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pairs.html#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fprivate%2Flist..rkt%29._foldl%29%29), so you have to use some recursion, placing pictures on the scene one by one:

```
(require 2htdp/image)
(require 2htdp/universe)

(define scene (empty-scene 500 500))
(define-struct pos (x y))
(define-struct ball (img pos))

(define (place-on-scene scene lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      scene
      (place-on-scene
       (place-image (ball-img (first lst))
                    (pos-x (ball-pos (first lst)))
                    (pos-y (ball-pos (first lst)))
                    scene)
       (rest lst))))

(define (render lst)
  (place-on-scene scene lst))

(define game (list
              (make-ball (circle 10 "solid" "blue") (make-pos 250 250))
              (make-ball (circle 10 "solid" "red") (make-pos 150 150))))

(big-bang game
  [to-draw render])
```